# Failing query, don't understand why

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have this query, which I don't know why it doesn't work, even though if I change some parameters, it works just fine. Here is the query:

```
SELECT round(ST_Distance_Sphere(
                       (SELECT coordinates FROM houses WHERE id = 7)),
                       (SELECT wkb_geometry FROM coastline ORDER BY wkb_geometry <->
                       (SELECT coordinates FROM houses WHERE id = 7)) LIMIT 1)
                       )) AS DISTANCE;
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LIMIT"
>   LINE 4: (SELECT coordinates FROM houses WHERE id = 7)) LIMIT 1)

This works:

```
SELECT round(ST_Distance_Sphere(
                 ((ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10.806527 54.101916)',4326))),
                 (SELECT wkb_geometry FROM coastline ORDER BY wkb_geometry <->
                 ((ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10.806527 54.101916)',4326))) LIMIT 1)
                 )) AS DISTANCE;
```

I tried removing `LIMIT`, but it leads me to problems with the parentheses, and there is where I get lost.

Answer (score 1):

`ST_Distance_Sphere` has first argument `(SELECT coordinates FROM houses WHERE id = 7)` then you close `)`, so `(SELECT wkb_geometry...` is second argument for `round`, which I suppose is not what you want.

So I believe you just got lost in parentheses - try rewriting code "in ladder" so every parenthesis has closing one in same indentation...

based on your working query - are you trying to do this?

```
SELECT round(
  ST_Distance_Sphere(
    ((SELECT coordinates FROM houses WHERE id = 7 LIMIT 1)
  ,
  (SELECT wkb_geometry FROM coastline ORDER BY wkb_geometry <-> (SELECT coordinates FROM houses WHERE id = 7) LIMIT 1))
)) AS DISTANCE;
```

Comment: Yes, I'm trying something like that, but still gives an error on `LIMIT 1`

Comment: updated to avoid error